# Request.Form.Get from a select option tag error

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im trying to get a value or a text from the "select option" tag through C#, but I run on some issues :

this is my code :

```
<select id="country" >
                        <option value="" >Select One...</option>
                        <%for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                          {%>
                            <option value="<%=dt.Rows[i][0].ToString() %>" ><%=dt.Rows[i][1].ToString() %></option>  
                          <%} %>
                        </select>
```

and this is my code behind :

```
string value = Request.Form.Get("country");
```

its keep getting `null` in my value. and if Im trying to set my `<select>` tag with `runat="server"`, its getting an error :

> Code blocks are not supported in this context

any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Form elements are posted by their name attribute, not id.

Try

```
<select id="country" name="country">
```